# Force document end in PHP

Tags: php, flush

I am trying to flush output to the browser and then disconnect the user on the MAC level.  However, my script never actually finishes loading the browser, it shows loading but the meta refresh wont become active until this page actually finishes.  Are their any functions I can do that will finish the output and let PHP do its own thing with out hanging on to the user.

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) {
  ob_start();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
  <head>      
    <title>Loading... </title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;URL='nexturl.php'" />  
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>Loading... (lots of whitespace here)</p> 
  </body>   
</html> 
<?php 
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_end_flush();
sleep(1);

// This function kills their connection on their computer instantly
disconnect_user_on_their_router();
?>
```

Comment: `exit;`?  Or do you need to have the PHP continue _after_ the document end.

Comment: If you want the PHP to run without the user noticing, you should use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

To terminate, but still buffer, you can call these (in this order):

```
flush();
ob_flush();
exit();
```

However, I'm not sure how this would interact with your router-killer (which you'd need to call before `exit`).

Comment: I was looking at exit as well, however if I exit the script, it will never get to that function.  If I call that function, the exit will technically work on the server end but the there will be no more client anymore.